# fetch record as in order passed for IN condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch the records in order passed for IN condition.

select * from table where id in(6,3,7,1);
 is returning the rows as

```
id   name
1     abc
3     xy
6     ab
7     ac
```

but I want to display the records in same orders as ids passed in condition in Oracle

```
id   name
6     ab
3     xy
7     ac
1     abc
```

Please help me in  fetching the records in same order as in condition ids in oracle. The values in IN condition may change dynamically.

Comment: You cannot do that with the IN. You must UNION 4 SELECTs of a single row.

Comment: @Frazz . . . `union` is not guaranteed to return things in any order.  And, I specifically doubt that it would work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `case` statement in the `order by` clause or using a `join`.

```
select *
from table 
where id in(6,3,7,1)
order by (case id when 6 then 1 when 3 then 2 when 7 then 3 when 1 then 4 end);
```

Or:

```
with ids as (
      select 6 as id, 1 as ordering from dual union all
      select 3 as id, 2 as ordering from dual union all
      select 7 as id, 3 as ordering from dual union all
      select 1 as id, 4 as ordering from dual
     )
select *
from table t join
     ids
     on t.ids = ids.id
order by ids.ordering;
```

Note that you don't need the `in` in this case, because the `join` does the filtering.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for quick response.  I want to make it dynamic that means passing values in IN condition will change dynamically.

Comment: @Ravi . . . You can make it dynamic.  You just have to work harder putting the query together.

Answer (score 0):

you can use trick

```
select * from table where id in(6,3,7,1) order by case when id = 6 then 1
                                                            id = 3 then 2
                                                            id = 7 then 3
                                                            id = 1 then 4
                                                   end
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Agibov.  I am to pass the ids dynamically.  The number of ids may change dynamically.